# Is Aurora Serverless V1 deprecated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

Aurora Serverless V1 was particularly interesting given it offered a relational database that could scale down to 0 units thereby costing nothing if unused - great for development and low traffic services.

Aurora Serverless V2 cannot scale down to 0 so it isn't really "serverless" as defined by other AWS serverless products (like Lambda and DynamoDB) and doesn't make it a cost effective replacement for V1 for low traffic websites.

Trying to provision a new Aurora Serverless V1 instance and it's nearly impossible to find an Aurora configuration that offers V1 support.

Is Aurora Serverless V1 deprecated/end of life?

Is there a practical alternative for a "serverless" relational DB where you pay for the storage and seconds of compute that you use?

Comment: No, its not deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

#### 01/01/2024 Update

End of Life email from AWS:

> We are reaching out to let you know that as of December 31, 2024, Amazon Aurora will no longer support Serverless version 1 (v1). As per the Aurora Version Policy [1], we are providing 12 months notice to give you time to upgrade your database cluster(s). Aurora supports two versions of Serverless. We are only announcing the end of support for Serverless v1. Aurora Serverless v2 continues to be supported. We recommend that you proactively upgrade your databases running Amazon Aurora Serverless v1 to Amazon Aurora Serverless v2 at your convenience before December 31, 2024.

Aurora Serverless V1 is not deprecated and is still widely available. However, while it can scale to zero it lacks a lot of the features that Serverless V2 has to offer and I expect to see that gap widen over time as new features get added to V2.

*If your application can run on MySQL 8.0 or PostgreSQL 13, we recommend that you use Aurora Serverless v2. Aurora Serverless v2 scales more quickly and in a more granular way. Aurora Serverless v2 also has more compatibility with other Aurora features such as reader DB instances.*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

Answer (score 0):

Aurora Serverless V1 for Postgres and MySQL are still available. The communication about [end-of-life](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.MySQL56.EOL.html) and [deprecation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.VersionPolicy.html#Aurora.VersionPolicy.MajorVersions) is confusing however, since there's some overlap in the "V1" lingo:

> Aurora MySQL 1 (deprecated)

the "1" is referring to MySQL 5.6, not "V1" Serverless.

> Amazon Aurora MySQL-Compatible Edition version 1 (with MySQL 5.6 compatibility) is planned to reach end of life on February 28, 2023

the "version 1" is referring to MySQL 5.6, not "V1" Serverless.

Comment: That's not true. You are conflating the Aurora Serverless version and the MySQL version, which are two different things. The article you linked links over to here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html to explain how to upgrade Aurora Serverless V1 from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora Serverless V1 is actually being phased out in 1 year from now. Official word was out on 28.12.2023 or around that date, I have it in my inbox. Like many other users of V1, I have also been using it mainly due to the possibility to scale down to zero.
However the 1 year heads up is fairly generous, so one just has to re-consider budgets.